# Condition on arguments of a function in Julia

Tags: function, methods, conditional-statements, julia, wolfram-mathematica

It is possible to specify the argument type for a function in Julia like : `addition(x::Int64,y::Int64)`. I can, simultaneously, define another function with the same name : `addition(x::Float64,y::Int64)`

Is it possible to also specify the above function such that instead of a restriction on type, I specify a restriction on the values `x` or `y` can take? So, for example, I could say that if `x` takes values between 1.0 and 15.0 then use one definition of `addition` and if it take values above 15.0 then use another definition.

So basically I would like to specify the range of values that the arguments of a function can take, like in Mathematica one can do : `addition[i_, j_] /; 0.0 <= i <= 15.0 && 0.0 <= j <= 15.0 := i + j`.

Thanks!

Comment: You can surely wrap your range-specific "additions" in a wrapper addition function where you soecific the logic, I don't think (but I may be wrong) that you can do it with the multiple dispatch mechanism..

Comment: @Antonello thanks, I was looking for a way to do it like Mathematica but yeah wrapping will work

Comment: I don't think Mathematica applies value-based multiple dispatch. You can write the conditional statement in one row like in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about what Mathematica does here, every programming language in history can do this, and Julia too.

```
addition[i_, j_] /; 0.0 <= i <= 15.0 && 0.0 <= j <= 15.0 := i + j
```

becomes

```
addition(i, j) = (0<=i<=15) && (0<=i<=15) && return i+j
```

But what should the function do if the inputs do not fall within the ranges? Right now it will return `nothing`.

Comment: Maybe `false` rather. But what Mathematica is doing here is (I think) a bit different. `/;` attaches this definition conditionally, but later definitions can also be attached, and the most specific matching one is always used. That is rather like Julia's dispatch, where you can always add more methods. But it allows values not just types -- the language is more dynamic, there isn't really a notion of compile-time. (Their help: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html )

Comment: @mcabbott yes, exactly my point - however, this answer does match what I asked and if very much acceptable as such!

Answer (score 2):

In the type you can hold concrete information and use it to dispatch.
For an example you could do

```
struct ValT{T}
    x::Float64
end
```

You could have than the following objects:

```
a=ValT{:small}(3)
b=ValT{:big}(100)
```

And you can dispatch accordingly:

```
f(u::ValT{:big}) = u.x + 1000;
f(u::ValT{:small}) = u.x + 10;
```

The only problem is that the values are known at the run time rather than the compile time and the function creating `ValT{}` will not be type stable.

Consider:

```
value(x) = ValT{x < 5 ? :small : :big}(x)
```

This function can be used to conveniently create an object with an appropriate type for your needs.

```
julia> value(4)
ValT{:small}(4.0)

julia> value(40)
ValT{:big}(40.0)
```

However there is a small issue - the function `value` creating `ValT` is not type stable and cannot be efficiently compiled:
[image: ``` ``]

This might be a problem or not depending on a particular use case scenario but basically should be avoided.